# Minimal install of debian, didn't install sound module, how to get sound working?

Tags: linux, audio, debian

I did a minimal install of debian wheezy and then upgraded to jessie. When installing wheezy, I didn't install any of the optional modules. I remember there being one about sound but I assumed I would be able to get anything necessary later on, so I didn't install it.

I installed `alsa alsa-base alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsamixergui` and have done a full reboot.

In VLC, there are three devices listed in Audio->Audio Device:

```
Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
```

I can get sound through my monitors by selecting their respective HDMI options. This is a little strange because one of them is displayport and the other is HDMI. However, the main problem is that Analog option doesn't work. I have working analog speakers plugged in but get no sound. I have tested that the speakers are in fact functional and not hardware muted. I have also put all of the volume bars to max in `alsamixer` and made sure none of them are muted.

What do I have to do to get my analog sound working?

```
lspci -vnn
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller [8086:0c0c] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8534]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 60
    Memory at dfe34000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:8ca0]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8619]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 61
    Memory at dfe30000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

and

```
aplay -l                                                        
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1150 Digital [ALC1150 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and

```
dmesg | grep sound
[   11.086000] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input14
[   11.089663] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input13
[   11.096971] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input23
[   11.097040] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Side as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input22
[   11.097071] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input21
[   11.097102] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input20
[   11.097136] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input19
[   11.097183] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input18
[   11.098098] input: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input17
[   11.098130] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input16
```

Comment: Have you tried running `alsamixer` and unmuting (`M` key) and pushing the volume fader up for all channels? Check the levels for every soundcard in alsamixer (`F6` key)

Comment: I'm such a fool :(. The channels WERE muted. For anyone else reading this. MM means muted and 00 means not muted. For some reason I thought it was the other way around.

Comment: Don't worry I've been there too :) Added my comment as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running `alsamixer` and unmuting (`M` key) and pushing the volume fader up for all channels? Check the levels for every soundcard in alsamixer (`F6` key)

`MM` means the channel is muted in alsamixer.